# how to change the list view in page zone

Tags: powershell, app, promoted-links

I have created a custom list with a custom view called "my view". I have added a custom list in page web part zone. I need to change the web part view as "my view" using PowerShell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$webURL = "http://SharePointSite"
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $webURL
$wpPage = $SPWeb.GetFile("Pages\Default.aspx")
$wpPage.Checkout()

$wpManager = $wpPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
for($i=0; $i -lt $wpManager.WebParts.Count; $i++) 
{ 
    if($wpManager.WebParts[$i].Title -eq "Posts") 
    { 
        $wp = wpManager.WebParts[$i]; 
        $wp.ViewGuid="{1E720D19-01A0-4B90-A14B-73CFC85092F8}"; 
        $wp.ViewId=8; // BaseViewID of View ex. 1 for AllItems.aspx
        $wpManager.SaveChanges($wp);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Sorry, I have updated the question with the new requirement.

Comment: I get error for : Exception calling "SaveChanges" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not
set to an instance of an object."

please Suggest any idea.

Comment: Please check object what you have used. for example, You are using $wpManager for $wpManager = $wpPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager() and save changes with  $wp object like $wp.saveChanges()

Comment: My code is :
$wpPage.Checkout()

$wpManager = $wpPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
for($i=0; $i -lt $wpManager.WebParts.Count; $i++) 
{ 
    if($wpManager.WebParts[$i].Title -eq "new view") 
    { 
 write-host -f green "Working fine"
        $wp = $wpManager.WebParts[$i]; 
        $wp.ViewGuid="{377365f4-b059-4770-834b-40785d877d3b}"; 
        $wp.ViewId=2;
        $wpManager.SaveChanges($wp)
    }
}

Comment: can u pls look my code? @VirajGorajia

Comment: Which is page you are using to add webpart?